# One html division being stacked over top of other

Tags: html, css

I am making a small webpage which is shown below . There is a footer at the end over which "Made with love by Vipul Tyagi" is written. The problem is that it is coming over the previous division(feedback form). No matter how much `top` property I apply to the footer, it is not moving down even a bit.

Please have a look at my code and help me to find the problem. You will find it at the very end in html just above `</body>` tag.

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#notif-list li").click(function(e) {
    var num = parseInt($("#notif-number").text());
    $(this).remove();
    $("#notif-number").html("" + num - 1 + "");
  });
});
```

```css
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
}

.fa-input {
  font-family: FontAwesome, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 55%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.heading {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', serif;
}

#headmain {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  left: -55px;
  color: white;
}

#headsecondary {
  position: relative;
  right: 5%;
  color: white;
}

#top-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

.number {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -2px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.borderimg {
  border-radius: 30%;
}

.carosel {
  width: 670px;
}

.service-list {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.labels {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.login-box {
  width: 320px;
  height: 520px;
  top: 290px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 70px 30px;
}

.login-box p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.login-box input {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.login-box input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  background: #1c8adb;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #39dc79;
  color: #000;
}

.login-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.login-box a:hover {
  color: #39dc79;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  .carosel {
    width: 300px;
  }
  .top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 55%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #headmain {
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    color: white;
  }
  #headsecondary {
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;
    right: 5%;
    color: white;
  }
  #service-list {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .login-box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">

  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="opacity: 0.9;top: 10px;">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="sankalpsoft.png" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;bottom : 10px;" /></a>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">SankalpSoft</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">Why We?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="color: white;" onMouseOver="this.style.color='yellow';" onMouseOut="this.style.color='white';">Notification<span class="number" id="notif-number">4</span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="notif-list">
                <li style="padding: 10px 5px;"><a href="#">Notification 1</a></li>
                <li style="padding: 10px 5px;"><a href="#">Notification 2</a></li>
                <li style="padding: 10px 5px;"><a href="#">Notification 3</a></li>
                <li style="padding: 10px 5px;"><a href="#">Notification 4</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container" style="width: 100%;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/PpNsdrDS/back-img.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width: 100%;height: 350px;filter: grayscale(10%) brightness(60%) contrast(1);box-shadow: 5px 15px 8px #888888;">
      <div class="top-left">
        <h1 class="heading" id="headmain">SankalpSoft Solutions</h1>
        <h3 class="heading" id="headsecondary">We Provide intelligent business support</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container carosel" style="height: 340px;top: 40px;">
    <h2 style="text-align: center;" class="service-list">Services We provide</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" style="box-shadow: 20px 10px 8px #888888;border-radius: 10%;">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active borderimg">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/kVQDWsY0/business.jpg" alt="business" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item borderimg">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XGnqL5Tp/outsourcing.jpg" alt="outsourcing" style="width:100%;">
        </div>

        <div class="item borderimg">
          <img src="ttps://i.postimg.cc/dDLwYnmJ/webdevelopment.jpg" alt="webdevelopment" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="item borderimg">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/K1T6YHRy/applicationdevelopment.png" alt="applicationdevelopment" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="item borderimg">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/gn105QC9/customersupport.jpg" alt="customersupport" style="width:100%;">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container login-box" style="position: relative;border-radius: 10%;">
    <h1 class="login service-list" style="text-align: center;">Feedback here</h1>
    <p class="login service-list labels">Name</p>
    <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="" id="usernm" required>
    <p class="login service-list labels">Contact No</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="" id="contact" required>
    <p class="login service-list labels">Message</p>
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="" id="msg" required>
    <input class="service-list" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="signupbut" class="login"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="container footer" style="position: relative;background-color: black;width: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 10px;">
    <p style="color: white; font-size: 20px;text-align: center;">Made with <span>&#10084;</span> by Vipul Tyagi</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**
Although I have found the solution, but I still don't understand what was the issue? I have never seen such behaviour with `top` prperty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your footer around a footer tag and use that tag to adjust the position on your page. The inline css i used is

```
  margin-top: 50%;
```

I've added a js fiddle for you as well. Take a look at this link:`https://jsfiddle.net/zfhassaan/5syxnme1/1/`

Comment: Your answer is giving the same result as mine. I observe no change

Comment: take a look at the jsfiddle i shared.

Comment: Yes I did, I think you didn't notice your own result

Comment: strange it's working on my end. Let me share the jsfiddle with you again.

Comment: Now it's working. But can you tell me had this been not a footer but a normal division, what would have we done then? I mean did you find what was wrong?

Comment: Your issue was in the css you applied on the footer. The normal division is also working i created the footer to organize the code. Just remove your margin: 0; from your last div inline css and apply the margin-top property to adjust it's position.

Comment: If it's the correct answer mark it as an answer for others as well.

Comment: The Js fiddle with your code and fixed css: https://jsfiddle.net/zfhassaan/c2jt4rsg/4/

Comment: Setting margin: 0 is not doing any good. I don't understand what is the problem. The footer is just ignoring the feedback form division and coming over its top

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212926/discussion-between-hassaan-ali-and-user13109153).

Answer (score -1):

In the style of class="container footer" , you have used position as relative. So, you can add top: some pixels (for eg: top: 200px) to your style, to keep the footer where ever you want.
For reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Please read my question again carefully. Setting top is not doing any good